# Ubuntu 13.04: How to keep nautilus' ftp connection alive?

Tags: linux, ftp, nautilus, ubuntu-13.04

I've installed ubuntu 13.04 today, and I'm having problems with ftp (via nautilus) disconnecting too quickly. On ubuntu 12, I used to prolong it by calling `ls ~/.gvfs/ftp*` every 20 seconds using a shell script. However, there's no .gvfs directory on ubuntu 13. Did the ftp mount folder just move elsewhere, or is it gone? What's the best way to keep the connection alive?

Answer (score 1):

edit:

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add these linies:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 5 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 6
```

Save and reboot system.

Comment: Initially up-voted this as it fixed the problem, but then started causing problems with other TPC traffic.

Comment: @GrahamLaming What kind of problems did you get? I have been using this for years with no problems, so I am curios what problems you have.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 but would have problems with mainly HTTP traffic. Would request web-pages and they would take a long time to resolve and load. Was suffering with this problem for a few days at home and at work. Removed these lines and everything was fixed. Put them back and the problems came back. Sorry this isn't a very technical answer, these are just my observations!